# What does "play games" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Being this direct (saying directly to other people) is easy when you know there is no need to play games with them or to impress them.

This sentence is in a paragraph that says you should talk directly to other people (especially women). Can "play games" in this sentence mean "deceive other people"? Or does it has another meaning?

Comment: I would say it means *no need to go overboard to make an impression*.

Comment: Actually, I believe that "play games" implies subtle manipulation or employing guile - both of which are directly opposite of "directness".  What has your own research shown?  Can you add it to your question?

Comment: This might help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamesmanship

Comment: I've edited my question. Do you think "play games" has another special meaning?

Comment: @WS2 But if so, why did the writer need to write that "or to impress them" after that?. They all have same meaning

Comment: @thegioibian I think it's just the 'belt and braces' way in which some people speak; like saying 'I don't want to cause pain and discomfort'. There is a word for this, which escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Having said that I think @Kristina has probably hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez.  If so, "play games" means "Discretion in speech" or "try to be appear clever in speech", right? And the sentence can rewrite that: "Being this direct (saying directly to other people) is easy when you know you can think aloud to other people (especially women) without worrying about what other people think of you", right?

Comment: It implies some sort of deceit, whether simply choosing words you wouldn't normally use or actually lying outright.  Generally the deceit is of the "harmless" variety -- "That's a lovely outfit you have on" -- vs something like saying a car for sale has a 10,000 mile warranty when it doesn't, but of course there's no hard boundary.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth It is play "games with someone"

Answer (score 0):

This is about *psychological games* or *mind games*.  Here is a nice breakdown of the basic types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_games

I remember when I was young, there was a book in the house called "Games People Play" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_People_Play_(book)).  I was big into board games, card games, charades, etc.  When I was bored and had run out of things to read, I would go trawling through the book shelves.  Every time I came across that title, I would open it up and be disappointed all over again.

Now that I am a more sophisticated reader than I was at age 10, I find mind games an interesting topic to read about.

Comment: Games People Play  deals with Transactional Analysis, a widely used  psychology technique  . It's a highly accessible methodology to interpret human behaviour ( basically, what does one really mean when he is saying or doing something) . Actually , if the sentence in focus did not end with  the part '' or to impress them"  the context might very well have been Transactional Analysis. There are other , more accessible books in that genre, mostly inadequately named, like "What do you say after you say hello" . Is not a sales pitch book despite its name, rather, quite a good read.

Comment: @aparente001. I've edited my question. Do you think "play games" has another meaning that is different from " psychological games or mind games" mentioned in your comment?

Comment: Some Example of Games under TA:  http://www.ericberne.com/games-people-play/marital-games/

Comment: @thegioibian - No, I don't think "play games" has another meaning in this sentence.  Can you explain why you are feeling doubtful?

Comment: @ aparente001 the sentence are about how a man should talk to other peole ((especially women). if "play games" means " psychological games or mind games", the sentence will be "Being this direct (saying directly to other people) is easy when you know there is no need to read other people’s minds", right?. I think it's not what the writer want to talk about. How do you think?

Comment: @thegioibian - I don't understand your last comment.  Could you edit your question, please, and be very careful to proofread your text, to minimize the chance of misunderstandings?  Thanks.

Comment: @ aparente001 Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to ask if "play games" means " psychological games or mind games", so "play games" will mean " read other people’s minds to interpret their thought (about you, for instance)", right?

Comment: @thegioibian - No, "play mindgames" is much more than just interpreting other people's hidden thoughts.  For example, someone who plays unpleasant mindgames might say one thing, and mean something quite different.  Dealing with people who play mind games can get very, very complicated.  Take a look at the references provided.